# Linux bjobs+bj1 -l: list log of every job listed, in a single linux command

Tags: linux

1. bjobs -g JobGroupName | grep RUN | awk '{print $1}' 
   lists All jobs being run
   Example lists following jobs:
   8299414
   8299410
2. bj1 -l 8299414 | awk '{print $44}' gives me run log for that job

As seen, I can get log for each job, but I dont want to manually do this for 100 jobs.
How do I combine step 1 and step 2, to list me all logs for all listed jobs? Pipe | didnt work. I believe something with foreach might do but cant yet figure an easy way.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct approach is a for loop:

```
for id in $(bjobs -g JobGroupName | grep RUN | awk '{print $1}'); do
  bj1 -l $id | awk '{print $44}'
done
```

I'm not familiar with the `bjobs`/`bj1` tools, but if they behave like `ps`, [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) is a good choice here -- it allows you to run some command with the output of STDOUT passed as arguments:

```
bjobs -g JobGroupName | grep RUN | awk '{print $1}' | xargs bj1 -l | awk '{print $44}'
```

Comment: Good deal -- `xargs` is a good tool for the command line toolbelt.

Comment: Yeah, wonder why it didnt strike me :) as I was trying with awk instead. Thank you for saving me bunch of time.